# If $f(z)=\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$ then $\text{Res}_{z=z_0}(f)=\lim\limits_{z\to z_0}\frac{1}{(k-1)!}\frac{d^{k-1}}{dz^{k-1}}(z-z_0)^kf(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Let $f(z)=\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}$ where $$p(z_0)=...=p^{(n-1)}(z_0)=0=q(z_0)=...=q^{(m-1)}(z_0),$$
$q^{(m)}(z_0),p^{(n)}(z_0)\neq 0$ and $p,q$ are holomorphic. Let $k=n-m$.

How can I show that if $k\geq 0$, then $f$ is holomorphic and if $k<0$, then $$Res_{z=z_0}(f)=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{1}{(k-1)!}\frac{d^{k-1}}{dz^{k-1}}(z-z_0)^kf(z).$$

Answer (score 0):

$p(z)=(z-z_0)^nP(z)$ and $q(z)=(z-z_0)^m Q(z)$ where $P$ and $Q$ are holomorphic and $P(z_0),Q(z_0)\neq 0$. Then, $$f(z)=(z-z_0)^{n-m}\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)},$$
where $\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$ are holomorphic around $z_0$. If $n-m\geq 0$, then $f$ is holomorphic. Suppose $n-m<0$. Since $z\longmapsto \frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$ is holomorphic and $\frac{P(z_0)}{Q(z_0)}\neq 0$, $$\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n$$
with $a_0\neq 0$. Then, Laurent series of $f$ is given by $$\sum_{k=n-m}^\infty b_k(z-z_0)^k.$$

You have that $Res_{z=z_0}(f)=b_{-1}$. You can see that if $k:=n-m\geq 0$, the function $f$ is obviously holomorphic. If $k<0$, then 
$$(z-z_0)^kf(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty d_n(z-z_0)^n$$ and thus$$\frac{\mathrm d ^{k-1}}{\mathrm d z^{k-1}}(z-z_0)^kf(z)=(k-1)!b_{-1}+G(z)$$
where $G(z)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k(z-z_0)^k$.

By taking the limit when $z\to z_0$, the claim follow.